# psittacism: Fundamental Theory of Time

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, constraint-programming

This question is in reference to the programming question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207624/selecting-non-overlapping-timetable-items).

---

What method of approach should I be thinking of if I have a list of lectures A, B, and C, and discussions D, E, and F, that are taught at times X, Y, and Z. Given that I must enroll in both a lecture and a discussion for each course, and I want to find out how to get all non-overlapping combinations of unique courses?

Answer (score 0):

Might consider making each unique class-discussion-lecture date object into a matrix like this:

[image]

Comment: Then use linear algebra to do build a comparison model!!!

Comment: Those times at the top of the image are in military time?

Comment: It won't be square though...